# Norm of operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider a complex Hilbert space $H$ and an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$. Define
$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}\lvert\langle Tx, y\rangle\rvert$$, $$\||T|\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\lvert\langle Tx,x\rangle\rvert$$

Can you find an example of a complex Hilbert space $H$ and an operator $T$ such that $\|T\|=2\||T|\|$. I've been thinking about it and I can't find it.

Comment: You can take $T = 0$.

Comment: It is true for any $T$ with $T^2=0$.

Comment: Interesting, if you desire $\|T\| = \alpha \||T\||$ for any $\alpha \in [1,2\rangle$, then such an example is given by:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 2} \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @mechanodroid Since $|||T|||\le\|T\|\le 2|||T|||$, $\alpha\in[1,2]$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take, for example, 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x^TTx|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|x_1x_2|=\sup_{t}|\cos t\sin t|=\frac12\sup_t|\sin 2t|=\frac12,
$$
but
$$
\sup_{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}|y^TTx|=\sup_{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}|y_1x_2|=1.
$$